# How can I reverse count a queryset in a for loop?

Tags: django, django-templates

My template code is this

```
{% for announcement in announcements %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ count }}</td>
        <td>{{ announcement.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ announcement.user.profile.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ announcement.modified }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to count down from the `length of queryset` to 1.

How can I do that?

Comment: I didn't understand what you want. Is the length of announcements  (`{{announcements|length}}`? What you mean the number to 1?

Comment: I mean count starts n and finish to 1. if annoucements have 3, count value would get each 3 and 2 and 1 in for loop.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a reverse counter called `forloop.revcounter` which counts from the length of the queryset to 1.

```
{% for announcement in announcements %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ forloop.revcounter }}</td>
        <td>{{ announcement.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ announcement.user.profile.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ announcement.modified }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

There are both zero (`forloop.revcounter0`) and 1 indexed (`forloop.revcounter`) reverse counting available.

[Django template "for" documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a counter which starts from 1 and increments while looping, you should use django's [`forloop.counter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

```
{% for announcement in announcements %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
        <td>{{ announcement.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ announcement.user.profile.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ announcement.modified }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```